# What are ALL_BUILD and ZERO_CHECK and do I need them?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

I've created a simple CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project (HelloWorld)
add_executable (HelloWorld main.cpp)
```

When I generate a VS2012 or VS2010 project from CMake, however, I get these 2 additional entries - ALL_BUILD and ZERO_CHECK.
I don't understand their purpose, do I need them?

[image]

Answer (score 94, accepted):

From https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2008-November/025448.html:

> Armin Berres — 11/22/2008, 3:12:41 PM
>
> ZERO_CHECK will rerun cmake. You can/should execute this after
> changing something on your CMake files.
>
> ALL_BUILD is simply a target which builds all and everything project
> in the active solution, I guess one can compare it to "make all".

Comment: ALL_BUILD doesn't necessarily build all projects. See https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_dir/EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL.html

Comment: ZERO_CHECK. Great naming; should serve as a stellar example to anyone trying to name new technologies. Keep up the good work CMake!

Comment: Be careful with the commends they might actually think the name is intuitive haha!

Comment: `ALL_BUILD` doesn't however build itself. :D You can take is as a proxy that triggers the build process in all other targets in the solution. This is rather confusing. The same applies to the `ZERO_CHECK`. which - as stated in the answer - reruns CMake hence it too doesn't build anything. I have no idea who decided to introduce this convention but I hope it changes in the future. For someone new to CMake and the integration into Visual Studio this is rather confusing.

Answer (score 39):

Add the following line to you CMakeLists.txt to suppress generation of ZERO_CHECK:

```
set(CMAKE_SUPPRESS_REGENERATION true)
```

Comment: Cool I did not know that. I tried CMAKE_SUPPRESS_REGENERATION:Bool=1 in CMakeCache.txt and it works too. Thanks

Comment: It should be noted that for some reason this needs to be set in the top-level `CMakeLists.txt`, it won't work in subdirectories (as of CMake 3.10)

Comment: Is there a similar way to prevent ALL_BUILD from being created?
Edit: Ok, there is not:
https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/16979